# Compare two pandas df columns with string values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two pandas df colums with populated with some names, first df has more name enteries, and second has less, e.g.

| id | names |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John Doe |
| 2 | Jane Doe |

| id | names |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John Doe |

I need to create a column with True/False in the first df, if names are matching, e.g.

| id | names | match |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John Doe | True |
| 2 | Jane Doe | False |

so far I have tried this two methodes:

```
df['match'] = (df1.names is df2.names) # always return False
df['match'] = df1.names.isin(df2.names) # compare only first names, eg. John, but doesn't the second
```

Additionally I have tried to lowercase and remove strings, but still not getting the result

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `df1.names.isin(df2.names.tolist())`

Comment: there is no "first name" and "second name" here........ there is only "names".......... so do you  want to compare "names" ?

Comment: @ThePyGuy thanks, but this also only compares the first name and not whole str.

Comment: @AnuragDabas ids are not matching, can't be used

Comment: @Joshua yes, I want to compare the whole str ('names'), but methode I used ither compares only the first part of the string and ignores the second or gives all false....

Comment: okay, if the existing answers don't work for you, provide the pair of source datasets (not dataframes). There could be easier way than using pandas, we can modify it directly from the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested the solution I provided in comment and it works, here is the sample run:

```py
>>> df1.names.isin(df2.names) #Additional call .tolist() isn't even required.
0     True
1    False
Name: names, dtype: bool
```

If above doesn't work, try this:

```py
>>> df1['names'].apply(lambda x: x in df2.names.tolist())
0     True
1    False
Name: names, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Which pandas version and python version are you using? Also update the question running the provided solution, and let us see if it's actually not working.

Comment: pandas version 1.3.0, python version 3.9.5

Comment: the second variant works perfect - many many many many thanks!